# Line After Table

Tags: google-docs

It seems that if you insert a table into a document, there is always a new line after it. This can be quite frustrating if the table is tall, as it keeps adding a blank page that is not required beneath the table.

Is there some special way of removing that line?

Comment: The closest I've come is to make it single line-height, 0 paragraph spacing, and a font size of 1pt.